# Slide background color transition

Tags: html, css

I found this example from a thread here in stackoverflow.

```
<a href="#">aosgibmoa bnocibnas</a>

a{
display:inline-block;
background:#fff;
position:relative;
padding:2px 5px;

background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.5, #000));
background-size:200% 100%;
background-position:0 0;
-webkit-transition:background-position .3s ease-out;
}

a:hover{
    background-position:100% 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nsfxE/1/

But I'm not sure how to change the -webkit-gradient to other vendor prefix and the normal standard one.

I want to make sure that it is somewhat modern cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.5, #000));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.5, #000));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.5, #000));
background-image: linear-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0.5, #fff), color-stop(0.5, #000));
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I found out for standard one is this, linear-gradient(to right, #fff 50%, #000 50%); . Still trying out for other prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried out and this is my answer. Hope this can be a reference to whoever is needed.

```
a{
display:inline-block;
background:#fff;
position:relative;
padding:2px 5px;
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(50%, #fff), color-stop(50%, #000));
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(left, #fff 50%, #000 50%);
background:-moz-linear-gradient(left, #fff 50%, #000 50%);
background:linear-gradient(to right, #fff 50%, #000 50%);

background-size:200% 100%;
background-position:0 0;
-webkit-transition:background-position .3s ease-out;
-moz-transition:background-position .3s ease-out;
transition:background-position .3s ease-out;
}

a:hover{
    background-position:-100% 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nsfxE/215/

Now it should work in most modern browsers.
I never put Opera prefix because I tried that and it doesn't work. Standard syntax works just fine on Opera.